# getting mysql error when running the query alognwith ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am getting " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server" error when running alongwith ssh command :

```
ssh user@localhost echo "delete from partner_company_association where colId = \"default.col \";" | /usr/bin/mysql -h localhost dbname
```

But the same works fine without doing ssh and running directly in the box:

```
 echo "delete from partner_company_association where colId = \"default.col \";" | /usr/bin/mysql -h localhost dbname
```

Kindly help me in figuring out the mistake here. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does "default.col" come from?  Why is there a space at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong here - but isn't the `echo` command running on the server you're reaching via `ssh` - and the `/usr/bin/mysql` running on your local machine?

Whereas, both commands are running on the remote machine when issued on the remote machine, without the `ssh`?

What if you moved the `ssh` call to after the pipe, on the `/usr/bin/mysql` command?

NOTE: It's been a while since I used Unix/Linux, but a quick Google check on `ssh` seems to indicate this is how it works....

Comment: Thanks for pointing that silly mistake . yes , moving ssh after | worked .